# Integrating Yii2 into Joomla and using Joomla's "user" table

Tags: php, joomla, yii2

Ultimately, I'm trying to integrate Yii2 into Joomla so that I can use Joomla's user management capabilities in conjunction with `Yii2's RBAC` capabilities. For example, I want to allow a user to `signup` using `Joomla's registration` process, but I want to define the roles and authentication rules using `Yii2's RBAC`.

The problem is that `Yii2` does not seem to be able to use `Joomla's "user"` table to lookup the user_id value for the currently logged-in user (which is necessary if I want to check permissions for logged-in users against Yii2's RBAC auth_assignment table).

NOTE: I am using the "basic" template alongside Joomla 3

Success criteria:
- `"Yii::$app->user->getId();"` should return the currently logged-in user's `user_id` from Joomla's `user` table
- Yii2's RBAC functions should also work and use Joomla's "user" table when looking up user_id --

```
if (Yii::$app->user->can('some-auth-item'))
    {
        return $this->render('some-page');
    }
```

Here is what I've attempted unsuccessfully thus far:

1) Added Yii2 to Joomla into index.php (this gets loaded without an issue)

LINK: http://www.yiiframew...ntegration.html
CODE:

```
require('/../../../basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/yii.php');
$yiiConfig = require('/../../../basic/config/web.php');
new yii\web\Application($yiiConfig); // Do NOT call run() here
```

2) Change default User table in models/User.php

LINK: http://stackoverflow...le-name-in-yii2
CODE:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
  {

      public static function tableName()
      {
         return 'fm3lk_user';
      }
```

3) Tested using the following code in index.php and logged-in to Joomla front-end using Admin account, but does not return a value

```
<?php 
        $zzz = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        echo $zzz;
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm really confused.  In general you are getting the logged in user id from the session not the table. If you need the user id from Joomla why don't you just do `$id = JFactory::getUser()->id`?

Comment: The reason is because I am using Yii2's RBAC function to verify the current user's privileges before running commands that I have defined in Yii2. Example: if (Yii::$app->user->can('some-auth-item'))    {       return $this->render('some-page');  } --- how do I configure Yii2 to get the userid from the Joomla login session and then use this id to check permission assignment in the auth_assignment RBAC table?

Comment: Well I showed you how to get it, unfortunately  I don't know how to use it in Yii2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing basic user model with user identity.

When a user login in joomla it create a user session which is not connected to yii2 user identity (Yii::$app->user which, once initialized, get data from session anyway but different structure from joomla one).
In yii2 the user model implements the identity interface

```
    class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

Therefore after a joomla successful login you should login also the yii2.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login%28%29-detail

```
    $userModel = new User;
    $userModel->findIdentity($joomlaUserId);
    Yii::$app->getUser()->login($userModel, $duration);
```

where $userModel implement yii\web\IdentityInterface and is mapped over joomla user table, have $duration match the joomla session duration.
After that you will get access to Yii::$app->user->getId();

At joomla logout lougout yii2 app as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new User model with gii from Joomla's user table. I think it could be an easier starting point.